# Check whether an event is within a timeframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have a model for timeframes defined by:

```
STARTTIME: HH:MM
ENDTIME: HH:MM
```

Now i need to do a query with a given time `ACTUALTIME` in the format HH:MM, and check whether `ACTUALTIME` is within the any of my given Timeframes defined by: `STARTTIME` and `ENDTIME`.

Since the Ruby time object when defined only by the Hour and Minute is always represented by a date, i wonder wether there is any possibility to query something like:
Is 13:40 between 11:00 and 15:00 without taking the date part into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Phrogz advice I figured out how to write a method which can compare two times independent from their date. It works fine for me even when the `ENDTIME`is after 24:00

```
def betweenTime(timestart, timeend, timecheck)

 getseconds = lambda{ |time| time.hour*60*60 + time.min*60 + time.sec}

 timestart = getseconds[timestart]
 timeend = getseconds[timeend]
 timecheck = getseconds[timecheck]


 if (timeend-timestart) < 0
   timeend = timeend + (60*60*24) # add seconds for one day if timeend is after 24:00
 end

 timecheck.between?(timestart, timeend)
end
```

Comment: Note that defining one method inside another like that in Ruby is not like it is in JavaScript: you redefine a new `getseconds` methods in the same scope (not private) each time you invoke `betweenTime`. You may instead want `getseconds = lambda{ |time| … }; timestart = getseconds[timestart]`.

Comment: Note that this does not work in the case of
`timestart: 21:30`
`timeend: 04:30`
`timecheck: 02:00`

Due to the fact that you're not altering `timecheck` if `timeend` is after 24:00, and therefore in this case it's numeric value is smaller than `timestart` AND smaller than `timeend` resulting a `false` return value...

Answer (score 1):

If your `HH:MM` are strings, and they are always zero-padded (e.g. "03:08") then you can just use a simple string comparison:

```
irb:02> first = "03:17"; last = "11:54"
#=> "11:54"
irb:03> range = first..last
#=> "03:17".."11:54"
irb:04> range.include? "00:00"
#=> false
irb:05> range.include? "03:50"
#=> true
irb:06> range.include? "03:09"
#=> false
irb:07> range.include? "12:17"
#=> false
irb:08> range.include? "11:17"
#=> true
```

If your STARTTIME and ENDTIME are coming into Ruby as instances of `Time` then you can either write a method to convert them to strings (`my_time.strftime('%H:%M')`) or you can simply write a comparator:

```
# Returns true if hour:min is between the times in t1 and t2
def between(hour,min,t1,t2)
  t1.hour<=hour && hour<=t2.hour && t1.min<=min && min<=t2.min
end
```

Comment: Thanks Phrogz,
both solutions seem to work perfect as long as ENDTIME is not after 24:00 like: STARTTIME 19:00 ; ENDTIME 03:00.
But with the hep of your code i figuered out how to write a method which does the job. attached here